# How to make a XAML-only animation of a ScaleTransform (render transform) work via an EventTrigger on event Loaded?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, eventtrigger, loaded

I have an `UserControl` with `RenderTransform` set to a `ScaleTransform`. I try to animate its `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties in a `Storyboard` inside an `EventTrigger` with `RoutedEvent`=`Loaded`, but the animation does not take place.

I have tried changing the Duration of the `DoubleAnimation`s, I tried to explicitly set the target properties of the animations with the long syntax (e.g. `(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)` instead off `ScaleX`), I tried to change the initial values set to the `ScaleTransform` when it is constructed in markup.

## MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="cs_wpf_test_18.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cs_wpf_test_18"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="cs_wpf_test_18.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cs_wpf_test_18"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Background="Blue" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">

    <UserControl.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" x:Name="MyRenderScaleTransform"/>
    </UserControl.RenderTransform>

    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=MyRenderScaleTransform}"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                         From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=MyRenderScaleTransform}"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                         From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
</UserControl>
```

The animations do not work, instead the animations do not start at all and the initial values set when constructing the `ScaleTransform` in XAML are shown in the UI.

## Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set `Storyboard.Target`.

Just directly animate the  properties of the ScaleTransform object in `RenderTransform`:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                     From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <BackEase/>
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                     From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <BackEase/>
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

Alternatively, set `Storyboard.TargetName`:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRenderScaleTransform"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                     From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <BackEase/>
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRenderScaleTransform"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                     From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <BackEase/>
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: It works, but I wish, if possible, to know why my initial markup does not work. Thank you.